# Chain meta_search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope, meta-search, active-relation

How can I chain metasearchs' search method ?

```
@result = User.search(params[:search]).search(params[:filters])
```

We can call chain method on ActiveRecord like

```
User.active.male.where( age: 14..20)
```

its chaining is possible on meta search's result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working.. If you had the same problem, you can try following.

The search method of `meta_search` returns `MetaSearch::Search::ModelName` where `ModelName` is the name of your model. Meta_search provides a method `relation` for this object. You can call `relation` method to get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and then you can call the search method again on that object. See the code below to see what I am exactly talking about.

```
@result = User.search(params[:search])
@search = @result.relation.search(params[:filters])
```

Here `@result` is the instance of `MetaSearch::Search::User` so we can call `relation` method to get an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` i.e

```
@result.relation
```

and then we can call search method again on this instance. i.e

```
@result.relation.search(params[:filters])
```

Answer (score 2):

What about searching in one go

```
@result = User.search  params[:search].merge(params[:filters])
```

Comment: It cannot be done in one go.

params[:search] have a key "user_notes_note_name_equals"
params[:filters] also have a key "user_notes_Note_name_equals"

but both have different values to search. So if we merge them then there will be only one key "user_notes_note_name_equals" with the latest assigned value as both keys are same. The previous value will be overwritten.

Comment: Oh man then your search result should be empty and it'll always return empty result.how can one note_name have two name ? as for as i understand meta_search's generated query would be like "SELECT * form users (join here) WHERE user_notes.name = 'blah' AND user_notes.name = 'blah2". are you sure you have two keys with same name is not second key used for orders ?